# angularjs's ng-click not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I write under angularjs source code.

I click Test1 but show alert .

What?

Help me, please.

My HTML is

```
<html ng-app="Login">
    <head>
        <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/script" src="http://www.air.com/js/Login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" ng-click="behaviour()">test1</a></li>
                    <li>test2</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript is

```
var app = angular.module('Login', []);
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope){
    $scope.behaviour= function() {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean? inside your function you have `$window.alert("??");` so you see an alert with two question marks. What's the issue?

Comment: what do you want the code to do?

Comment: I want to see javascript alert when click "test 1".
I am not good at English, sorry.

Comment: Don't you see the text "clicked" in the alert box?

Comment: I can only assume that `http://www.air.com/js/Login.js` is supposed to load the Javascript? Upon navigating their myself, it doesn't.

Comment: You should see angular errors in browsers console as the `Login` module is not available since `http://www.air.com/js/Login.js` does not bring your angular app definition.

Comment: Check this  , Ithink you forgot http:// in src   field   otherwise its working fine <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script> use this <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find your error! change your angular source, and try again

```js
var app = angular.module('Login', []);
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope){
    $scope.behaviour= function() {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```css
a{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="Login">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a ng-click="behaviour()">test1</a></li>
                    <li>test2</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```